# From a Roman Catholic canon law perspective, is it accurate that certain Old Catholic churches are in "limited intercommunion"?

Tags: catholicism, communion

I have seen several Old Catholic (Union of Scranton) clergy or affiliates claim that their churches (the Polish National Catholic Church and Nordic Catholic Church) enjoy “limited intercommunion” with the Roman Catholic Church (see [X posting by Fr Calvin Robinson](https://twitter.com/calvinrobinson/status/1712579617125437726))

From a Roman Catholic perspective, is this claim true? Does the Roman Catholic Church under canon law regard itself as in limited intercommunion with the PNCC and NCC, or is this a one-sided view from the Old Catholics?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 1):

**From a Roman Catholic canon law perspective, is it accurate that certain Old Catholic churches are in “limited intercommunion”.**

The short answer is no. They are not in communion with the Roman Catholic Church.

Roman Catholic and Eastern Rite Catholics can not receive the sacraments from priests of the Old Catholic Church. Furthermore Roman Catholic priests are forbidden to concelebrate the Eucharist with ministers who are not in full communion with Rome. The Old Catholic Church denies several Roman Catholic doctrines and as such the two are not in full communion at all.

> [Can. 908](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib4-cann879-958_en.html) Catholic priests are forbidden to concelebrate the Eucharist with priests or ministers of Churches or ecclesial communities which do not have full communion with the Catholic Church.

Their idea of a “limited intercommunion”, in the eyes of Roman Catholicism is totally untrue, even if they have valid sacraments.

> **The Origins of Old Catholicism**
>
> The origins of Old Catholicism can be traced back to the First Vatican Council, which was convened by Pope Pius IX in 1869. One of the main issues addressed at the council was the doctrine of papal infallibility. This doctrine held that the pope, when speaking ex cathedra on matters of faith and morals, was infallible and could not err. This was seen as a controversial development by many Catholics, who believed that it represented a departure from traditional Catholic teaching.
>
> A group of bishops, led by the Archbishop of Utrecht in the Netherlands, Johannes Heykamp, opposed the doctrine of papal infallibility and walked out of the council. They argued that the pope was not infallible and that the doctrine was not consistent with the teachings of the early Church. This group of bishops became known as the Old Catholics.
>
> In 1870, after the First Vatican Council had ended, the Old Catholics held their own council in Nuremberg, Germany. At this council, they rejected the doctrine of papal infallibility and also adopted a number of other reforms. These included the use of the vernacular in liturgy, the right of priests to marry, and a greater emphasis on the authority of local bishops.
>
> **Beliefs of Old Catholicism**
>
> Old Catholicism shares many beliefs with Roman Catholicism, but there are also some important differences. Like Roman Catholics, Old Catholics believe in the Holy Trinity, the Virgin Birth, and the Resurrection of Jesus Christ. They also recognize the seven sacraments, including baptism, confirmation, and the Eucharist.
> However, there are some areas of disagreement between the two traditions. Old Catholics reject the doctrine of papal infallibility and do not recognize the pope as the supreme authority in the Church. Instead, they emphasize the role of local bishops and believe in a more decentralized Church structure. Old Catholics also allow priests to marry, which is not permitted in the Roman Catholic Church. Additionally, Old Catholics use the vernacular in liturgy, while Roman Catholics traditionally used Latin.
>
> Old Catholicism also places a strong emphasis on ecumenism and interfaith dialogue. They believe in the unity of all Christians and have sought to build bridges with other Christian traditions, including the Anglican Communion and the Eastern Orthodox Church. This commitment to ecumenism has led to some controversial decisions, such as the decision to allow intercommunion with the Anglican Communion, which has been opposed by some conservative Catholics.
>
> **Intercommunion between Old Catholicism and the Anglican Communion**
>
> The intercommunion between Old Catholicism and the Anglican Communion, which was established by the Bonn Agreement, has been controversial within the Catholic Church. Some conservative Catholics have opposed the agreement, arguing that it undermines the authority of the pope and the Roman Catholic Church.
>
> However, proponents of the agreement argue that it is an important step towards Christian unity and ecumenism. They believe that it is possible to recognize the validity of each other’s sacraments without compromising the distinctive beliefs and practices of each tradition.
>
> [An overview of the Old Catholic churches and their relationship to the Roman Catholic Church](https://medium.com/@BishopRick/an-overview-of-the-old-catholic-churches-and-their-relationship-to-the-roman-catholic-church-7a27ed48e09c)

Rome has already determined that Anglican Orders are invalid. Yet the Old Catholic Church has intercommunion with Anglicans. This also deteriorates the possibility of any chance of a future ecumenical hope of an establishment of a full communion with the authorities at the Vatican.

On September 13, 1896, Pope Leo XIII declared all Anglican Orders null and void. See: [(***Apostolicae Curae*** On the Nullity of Anglican Orders)](https://www.papalencyclicals.net/leo13/l13curae.htm). For the Old Catholic Church to permit intercommunion with their faithful and the Anglican Communion presents serious obstacles to any possibility of intercommunion with Catholics of the Roman Rite.